# How big a privacy concern is the fact that any program can access any file from home directory directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, malware

In Linux and Windows, a program can easily access any file from any directory using `fopen ()`.
We know how program data is stored in Linux distros in your home directory in `.config`. This means a malware can easily read your data. Also a malware can access media by default.
How then this isn't a major concern for privacy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the weakness of a security model that is user-based (trying to assign rights based on the notion of a user) versus a security model based on capabilities (specific rights to objects such as files, directories are given through well defined interfaces rather than assumed based on the user).

User-based security models have an inherent weakness in that:

- it's assumed the user knows what the user is doing at all times;
- programs launched under the user's session are assumed to be intentionally launched by the user;

This model is preferred by people who know a lot about computers and know what they are doing, but for appliance-type devices that are really only used by a single user, that model breaks down and can lead to problems if the user doesn't want to assume total responsibility for learning the system.

Thus, operating systems like Android and Apple are more capability based (even though they are Linux/UNIX under the hood) and try to implement models where programs need specific capabilities enabled to do specific things, rather than just get a large set of permissions to things based on the "user" they are running as.

Comment: Is the same kind of access possible for Windows as well?

Comment: @CodesterClub - Is what kind of access possible on Windows?

Comment: @CodesterClub - You can use this answer as a starting point for research.  I don't think there's a real OS out there that's 100% capability based, and the notion of users as an integral part of OS objects is probably never going away.  You can look into things like the NTRights from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit tools as a starting point of how Windows kinda-sorta implements capabilities and how it interacts with the notion of users.  You also may want to take a deep dive into Google's Fuschia and SELinux for more information.